# Error while trying to pull docker image in IBM Cloud VM behind proxy server

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, docker-image

> Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping: proxyconnect tcp:
>   dial tcp: lookup =https: no such host

We are trying to pull docker image in our VM which has os RHEL7.

```
docker pull hello-world
```

Getting below error while running the above command.

```
Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup =https: no such host
```

Our VM is behind a proxy server. Also we have configured docker to use the proxy server as well. 
Confirmed the proxy config for docker by running below command -

```
sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker
```

and output is as below -

```
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash DOCKER_HTTP_HOST_COMPAT=1 PATH=/usr/libexec/docker:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin HTTPS_PROXY=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:443/ HTTP_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/
```

However if I do `wget https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/_ping`, it works fine. Anything I am missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

this error has no specific solution, after googling you may try one of the following:

1- change DNS to `8.8.8.8` in /etc/resolv.conf.

2- just restart `Docker` daemon.

3- Uninstall and re-install `Docker`.

4- Follow the steps in [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) to setup the proxy.

Comment: I did modify the `/etc/resolve.conf` file and add `8.8.8.8`. It didn't work. I think 8.8.8.8 is blocked in our VM.

Comment: Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 is not possible. actually 8.8.8.8 is blocked on the server. Is there a way to check if the already present namespace entry in resolve.conf is good enough?